# My Form Discard User Inputs When I Remove My Browser From Recent Tabs How To Fix

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I Have Made A Form With a Little JavaScript Which Saves User Inputs When User Puts It's Information. It Saves User Information For Some Time Like When I Refresh Page It Save Information In Form But When I close my Browser From Recent Tab It Discard All Information Of User Please Make It To Save Information Even When Page Is Refreshed And When Browsers Is Closed From Recent Tabs

HERE IS THE FORM

```
<div class='contact-form-widget shamweel-billing-form'>
<div class='form contact-form shamweelcustomform'>
<form id="gform" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" data-email="appsnationmail@gmail.com" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxDNkQyUVZNDXinumdYnsa_NKpApi5WRHdQwCxVwGejw02Io9k/exec">      
<input class='contact-form-name contact-style' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Your Name' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='contact-form-email contact-style' id='email' name='email' placeholder='Email Address' size='30' value='' type='email' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-city contact-style' id='phone' name='phone' placeholder='Phone Number' size='30' value='' type='number' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-address contact-style' id='address' name='address' placeholder='Apartment, Street Name, etc' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-city contact-style' id='city' name='city' placeholder='City' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-state contact-style' id='state' name='state' placeholder='State' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-postal contact-style' id='postal' name='postal' placeholder='Postal/Zip Code' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<input class='shamweelcustomform-state contact-style' id='service' name='Service Type' placeholder='Wash Service Type' size='30' value='' type='text' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'/>
<textarea class='shamweelcustomform-message contact-style' id='message' name='message' placeholder='Order Notes' onkeyup='saveValue(this);'></textarea>
        <button class="contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit">Send</button>
       </form>
     </div>  
    </div>
```

HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("name").value = getSavedValue("name");    
     document.getElementById("email").value = getSavedValue("email");   
     document.getElementById("phone").value = getSavedValue("phone");    
     document.getElementById("address").value = getSavedValue("address");   
     document.getElementById("city").value = getSavedValue("city");    
     document.getElementById("state").value = getSavedValue("state");   
     document.getElementById("postal").value = getSavedValue("postal");    
     document.getElementById("service").value = getSavedValue("service");   
     document.getElementById("message").value = getSavedValue("message");    
     
     

     
     function saveValue(e){
         var id = e.id;  
         var val = e.value; 
         localStorage.setItem(id, val);
     }

     
     function getSavedValue  (v){
         if (!localStorage.getItem(v)) {
             return "";
         }
         return localStorage.getItem(v);
     }        
</script>
```

Comment: Please Don't Write Everything In Title Case.

Comment: It seem it is working fine. I cleared my history also. Still browser retain information. Are you placing that `<script type="text/javascript">` inside `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works well too, but try attaching the `onbeforeunload` event. this works for me.

```
function dataSave() {
    /*here write your command localStorage.setItem()*/
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}

function dataSaveExit() {
    setTimeout(dataSave, 0);
}

window.onbeforeunload = dataSaveExit();
```